# Swift split string at first match of a character

Tags: ios, string, swift

I'm trying to make an iOS app in Swift that requires me to split a line of text at the first colon (:) of a line. I've tried using the the componentsSeparatedByString method on the string, but in addition to getting an error stating "'NSString' does not have a member named 'componentSeparatedByString'", that method doesn't actually do what I want.

For a bit more context, I'm trying to separate a line in a play, that being of the form

```
<character name> : <line>
```

into the character's name and the line. I am assuming there is no colon in the character's name, so I want to split at the first colon in the line, so that I won't break the line's text into pieces if there are any colons in the text.

So, my first question: Why isn't the use of 'componentsSeparatedByString' valid in the following code: (the following code isn't the situation I mentioned before, but it's something I want to fix and keep in, so I wanted to use it instead of the colon breaking code.)

```
var fileRoot = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("LonelyImpulse", ofType: "txt")
    var contents = NSString(contentsOfFile:fileRoot!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
    let stringArray = contents.componentSeparatedByString("\n")
```

And my second: How can I split the string along just the first match of the colon (:) character, rather than along all matches?

Answer (score 10):

Swift 2 answer with **split** function(for Swift 3 use maxSplit**S** parameter, just add "s"):

```
let fullString = "A B C"
let splittedStringsArray = fullString.characters.split(" ", maxSplit: 1).map(String.init)
print(splittedStringsArray) // ["A","B C"]
```

Comment: Note `fullString.split` is sufficient, at least in Swift 5

Answer (score 10):

Swift 4.2, Swift 5 answer:

```
let str = "Hello, this is, a,  playground"
let splitStringArray = str.split(separator: ",", maxSplits: 1).map(String.init)

print(splitStringArray) // ["Hello", " this is, a,  playground"]
```

Answer (score 7):

**the first**

It's just a typo, not `componentSeparatedByString`, but `componentsSeparatedByString`

```
let stringArray = contents.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
//                                  ^
```

**the second**

You can use builtin `split` function which can specify `maxSplit`:

```
let str:NSString = "test:foo:bar"
let result = split(str as String, { $0 == ":" }, maxSplit: 1, allowEmptySlices: true)
// -> ["test", "foo:bar"]
```

Note that the type of the result is `[String]`. If you want `[NSString]`, just cast it:

```
let result:[NSString] = split(string as String, { $0 == ":" }, maxSplit: 1, allowEmptySlices: true)
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I **strongly** recommend using split, there is a nasty problem when using componentsSeparatedByString on Swift 1.2.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz, what is the nasty problem?

Comment: @Suragch I don't recall *exactly*, but it was a bridging problem that caused nonsense errors. I only debugged it by changing another line of code and noticing it didn't crash although it was ostensibly doing the same thing.

Comment: How would you modernize the second function for swift 3?

Comment: The docs for the `maxSplits` option read: `Returns the longest possible subsequences of the collection, in order, around elements equal to the given element.` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2894564-split). The `longest possible` phrase seems odd to me. No matter what I try, with split = 1, it always splits at the first occurrence of the separator.