# String componentsSeparatedByString do one time

Tags: ios, string, swift, split

I have a string: 
`let mystring = "key=value=value=value=value"`

When i did:

```
let ar = mystring.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
```

i get:

`["key", "value", "value", "value", "value"]`

but i need do split only once, like `componentsSeparatedByString("=", 1)`, to get:

```
["key", "value=value=value=value"]
```

Comment: so you want only it to separate components only for the first "=" sign?

Comment: to the number that i set, it can be two, three, etc..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181282/swift-split-string-at-first-match-of-a-character Is this what you are trying to do, split at the first = in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Swift 2.1, you can use the split function as follows to do what you want:

```
let result = string.characters.split("=", maxSplit: 1, allowEmptySlices: true)
```

Some example code to test this would be:

```
let string = "key=value=value=value=value"
let result = string.characters.split("=", maxSplit: 1, allowEmptySlices: true)
print(String(result[0]))  // "key"
print(String(result[1]))  // "value=value=value=value"
```

Comment: That works, although it's cleaner if you add a map to the end, e.g. `let result = string.characters.split("=", maxSplit: 1, allowEmptySlices: true).map(String.init)`. How does that form of split work, though? The description of Split in the SequenceType protocol from the SwiftDoc.org site says `func split(maxSplit: Int, allowEmptySlices: Bool, @noescape isSeparator: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.SubSequence]`.

Comment: The code I came up with (which also works) is `let anArray = mystring.characters.split(1,
      allowEmptySlices: false,
      isSeparator: { $0 == "=" })
      .map(String.init)`

Comment: Equally valid code. Just a different way of writing the same thing. I agree that the `map` at the end makes it cleaner. There are multiple split functions defined. The one I'm using is defined in `extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable`.

Comment: Ugh. So there are 2 different split functions, one defined in the CollectionType extension and one defined in the SequenceType collection, and they take ALMOST the same parameters, but not quite? That seems messy and confusing.

Comment: I'm sure there are more than 2 split functions defined. Most of the swift standard library is messy and confusing to me.

Comment: Another question: What does `maxSplit: Int = default` mean? I'm familiar with defining default values for parameters with explicit constants, like  `maxSplit: Int = 4` but what does it mean to use the string `default`?

Comment: I wish I knew. I see that get used throughout the Swift standard library.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job

```
func extract(rawData: String) -> [String]? {
    let elms = rawData.characters.split("=", maxSplit: 1).map { String($0) }
    guard let
        key = elms.first,
        value = elms.last
        where elms.count == 2 else { return nil }
    return [key, value]
}
```

Example:

```
let rawData = "key=value=value=value=value"
extract(rawData) // > ["key", "value=value=value=value"]
```

Please note the `extract` function does an **optional** array of strings. Infact if the input string does not contain at least an `=` then `nil` is returned.

The code has been tested with the Swift 2.1 and Xcode Playground 7.1.1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to write your own custom code to do that, using either `NSScanner` or `rangeofString:options:range:`

### EDIT:

Actually, it sounds like the Swift String class's split function, with its `maxSplit` parameter, will do what you need. Take a look at the link  in Preston's answer.

Comment: @Arti please try my answer, I've already tested it and it works fine in swift 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
let mystring = "key=value=value=value=value"
let result = split(mystring as String, { $0 == "=" }, maxSplit: 1, allowEmptySlices: true)
```

result should now be [key, value=value=value=value]

Comment: should be split myString and there is no need to cast as String

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'String -> Bool' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (tested and working in playground)

```
var key = str.substringToIndex(str.rangeOfString("=")!.startIndex)
var value = str.substringFromIndex(str.rangeOfString("=")!.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
var resultingArray = [key, value]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, i found working solution for swift2:

```
let mystring = "key=value=value=value=value"
mystring.characters.split(1, allowEmptySlices: true, isSeparator: { $0 == "=" }).map(String.init)
```